# Finding a specific memory location in game?

Tags: memory, assembly, cheat-engine

I'm using cheat engine to find where in the game's memory certain properties are stored. For example - my player's health. Ultimately I want to write a program that will know where in memory to look so that my program can make decisions based on the current game state. I can and have found where in memory certain things are stored, the problem is that each time the game is opened the memory locations change. What do I need to do so that my program can work around the changing memory locations?

Comment: It is quite possible that you game using heap allocation to store its settings. The heap allocator will indeed give out a different address every time.  Have a look at the following links: https://www.google.nl/?client=firefox-b-ab#q=cheat+engine+heap+allocations&gfe_rd=cr

Comment: Try disabling ASLR for more predictable virtual memory layouts, hower you do that in whatever OS you're using.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that in your cheat engine table you're using hard coded addresses for these variables.  The variables are either dynamically allocated or are allocated staticly relative to the base address of a module.  To fix this you can use pointers to the variables, in which the pointers are staticly located or calculated at runtime using relative offsets from module base addresses.  You would use "Find out what accesses" to find pointers or the Pointer Scanner to do this.  You grab dynamic addresses of modules by using the [ToolHelp32Snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx) windows API function.  You can also use signature scanning to scan for an array of bytes that represent instructions that access the variable at runtime.  Then grab the address from the instruction operands.